# React TypeError: this.props.message.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, api, dictionary, axios, react-props

**I am trying to display messages on the screen which I receive from api. I checked in the debugger (here are the screenshots https://ibb.co/gShTG8g https://ibb.co/dQmfwJp) where all the stages are going fine, but in the end I get an error called *TypeError: this.props.message.map is not a function.* Here is my actual code, link to api https://rapidapi.com/ajith/api/messages**

**Messages.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
export class Messages extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const MessageList = this.props.message.map((item, index) => {
            return <div key={index}>
                <p>{item.Message}</p>
            </div>
        });
        return(
            <div>
                {MessageList}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**MessagesContainer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {Messages} from "./Messages";
import {getMessagesThunk} from "../../Redux/users-reducer";

class MessagesContainer extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getMessagesThunk();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <>
                <Messages {...this.props} />
            </>
        )
    }
}

let mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    message: state.usersPage.messages
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getMessagesThunk})(MessagesContainer);
```

**users-reducer.js (Here is a part of my code)**

```
let initialState = {
    messages: [],

};

        case MESSAGE:
            return {
                ...state, messages: action.messages
            }

export const getMessage = (messages) => ({type: MESSAGE, messages})

export const getMessagesThunk = (messages) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        usersAPI.message(messages).then(response => {
            if(response.data) {
                dispatch(getMessage(response.data.Message))
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Api.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

    const instance = axios.create({
        params: {category: 'love'},
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            "API-KEY": "6bec01a1-e00c-42ca-ab9d-a03ad2e730cc",
            'x-rapidapi-key': 'bf490d72a0msh3bf159a87e0c27fp107a51jsn062ca1b9b00e',
            'x-rapidapi-host': 'ajith-messages.p.rapidapi.com'
        }
    })
    
    export const usersAPI = {
        message() {
            return instance.get(`https://ajith-messages.p.rapidapi.com/getMsgs`)
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `message` is not an array you can loop through. It's a simple string.

[image]